# Ожидание монитора без его захвата. wait(), notify()

Tags: java, многопоточность

Добрый день.
Интересует такой вопрос:
Можно ли сделать так чтобы потоки ждали освобождения монитора но после того как монитор освободится они (потоки) не захватывали его?

Чтобы было понятнее опишу свою проблему.

Есть пул потоков. Каждый поток ждет сообщение из очереди сообщений.

```
public class MyService implements Runnable{
    private MessageSystem ms;

    public myService(MessageSysytem ms){
        this.ms = ms;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!interrupted){
            ms.execute(this);
            // Здесь система сообщений отдает потоку все сообщения для
            // потока и он их исполняет. Но если очередь пуста поток
            // будет гонять цикл просто так
        }
    }
}
```

Я бы хотел сделать так, чтобы в случае если очередь сообщений для этого потока пуста, поток ожидающий сообщение останавливался в ожидании (**monitor.wait()**). Но так как **wait()** нужно вызывать внутри блока синхронизации, то после ожидания он захватит монитор сам и другие потоки остановятся в ожидании.
Или может есть более правильные решения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно в таких случаях используют какую-нибудь блокирующую очередь для передачи сообщений от продюсеров к консамерам, например LinkedBlockingQueue:

```
public class MyService implements Runnable {

private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Message> queue;

public MyService(LinkedBlockingQueue<Message> queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (!interrupted) {
            Message msg = queue.take();
            processMessage(msg);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Спасибо, надо будет получше изучить java.util.concurrent))